# Android Settings activity not showing up

Tags: android, android-manifest, preferenceactivity

I am trying to create a Settings Activity using `PreferenceActivity`. But the after I click on the settings option, the settings activity does not load up, instead, it remains in same activity from where I am trying to load it.

Any help with regards to this issue is appreciated.

Thanks.

Below is the `SettingsActivity` code:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;


public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
    implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
    // TODO: Add preferences from XML

    // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
    // updated when the preference changes.
    // TODO: Add preferences
}

/**
 * Attaches a listener so the summary is always updated with the preference value.
 * Also fires the listener once, to initialize the summary (so it shows up before the value
 * is changed.)
 */
private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
    String stringValue = value.toString();

    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
        // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
    } else {
        // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

I also updated the `AndroidManifest.xml` with the `SettingsActivity`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call it from MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is my main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="never|withText" /></menu>
```